# org-babel-detangle writes duplicated code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming, tangle

I am trying to use `org-babel-detangle` for a while, but the source code is detangled twice in the main org file.

Interestingly, when I run `(org-babel-detangle "file_name.cpp")` it does not duplicate the cod.

About my setup:

- Framework: doom-emacs
- Emacs version: GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.17.8) of 2023-06-05

The main file that I mentioned have noweb been enabled and has several programming languages together. I tried using `:comments link` and `:comments noweb`, and both generated the same.

Is there any other alternative to detangle the code?

*Edit:* Changing to address one problem at a time

Comment: You present two problems about detangling. One question per post, please.

Comment: I just updated the question.